# Angular component is not rendering | angular 9.1.3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am not able to render component header in my application. I don't get any error also. In browser, It shows the header tag also but text present in header.component.html is not shown.

app.modules.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [HeaderComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Project';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<header></header>
<p>
Hello World

</p>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent{
}
```

Please help me. :'(

Comment: You should really use a prefix. App-header in this case. A <header> is already a valid html element.

Comment: Hi MikeOne, I have set prefix before header but I am getting the below error.
    ERROR in src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Comment: I should really start over with a clean install, use the defaults and use ng new and ng generate to create you components and services. It is not a good idea to start hacking in those core concepts if you’re just starting out.

Comment: Okay, I would try once. Thank you.